# Why is there extra space on the bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) for a site I'm working on and I can't get rid of an extra white space at the bottom.  I see it in Chrome and Safari (I haven't tested other browsers yet).  When the page first loads, you don't see it, but if you scroll down there is about 2-3px of just white space.  How to I make it so that my footer sticks to the bottom?

This is the site:

http://ec2-23-23-22-128.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

And this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

**How do I get rid of the extra white space at the bottom of the page?**

NOTE:  I know there are a couple of other rendering issues, but the only one I'm worried about right now is the extra pixles on the bottom of the page.  I've been playing with negative margins, 0 margins, paddings, etc all day and I'm not getting anywhere with it :/

Comment: The body automatically has a margin of 8px. Please post your css, almost impossible to determine without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It disappears when you give the image in the div with class "img-wrapper" `display: block`. This is common with images, I see you are doing this for a css reset:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

I would suggest against this. A proper [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) would go a long way to easing these kind of headaches.

Edit: I know you said it's a work in progress, but just as a heads up if you haven't noticed the window also scrolls when you don't need it to. This is the issue:

```
#b-container {
  background-color: #F1EFE6;
  min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -170px; // originally this was 0 auto -150px
}
```

Comment: Your comment about setting img-wrapper to `display: block` worked with the caveat of adding it to the img element as well.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was a little too vague. I did in fact mean that you should add it to the image inside the img-wrapper. You shoudn't need to add it to the img-wrapper itself because <div>s are already block elements. All the same I'm glad you have the solution.