# Blank space at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

Please visit <s>[this website](http://www.iamvishal.com/pureecn)</s>.

There is a blank space at the bottom. I checked it and there is no minimum height mentioned in my css.

I suspect it's in the body's css details as below:

```css
    body {
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-size: 87.5%;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
    }
    
    html, body, #page {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: no "blank space" here in Chrome.

Comment: I don't see any excess space at the bottom of the page. I'm running Firefox 20 in OpenSuse 12.3, and I have JavaScript disabled. Just in case that helps any.

Comment: Can you write an example for html code or write example in jsfiddle? I try your CSS code and i have not any problem...!

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021866/why-is-there-extra-space-on-the-bottom-of-page?rq=1

Comment: no blank spacer here because of 404.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This removed the bleed for me in Safari `6.0.3`;

```
#footer-wrapper {
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: url("../images/footer.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You might want to handle that overflow differently tho, based on the content inside it. But this should fix the white space.

I figured it out by just deleting nodes from the DOM bottom-up. It had to be in the `#footer-wrapper`. As margin-bottom didn't work and you were using relative positioning I figured it was some shadow styling bleeding out of that element.

**Update (better fix)**

Just found the real issue to the problem;

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Change `content: ".";` to `content: "";` and it's fixed. Or just remove that style at all, as it doesn't seem to have use in that case.

Comment: I had a similar problem as above but just adding `overflow: hidden;` fixed it for me, thx

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden;` to my `footer` element fixed a gap below my footer in Firefox and Edge; but I don't know why it works, and I wish I did..

Answer (score 2):

```
"overflow: hidden"
```

makes things harder but try,

```
"overflow: auto"
```

in order to be able to flow when you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the show here but it may help somebody in my case I had an empty space at the top I added the margin-top=-20px now the empty space at the bottom, tried almost all suggestions I found on these and many threads and nothing.  Decided to run it thru some HTML validator there are a few none of them pick up but after a couple one found an extra character(`) at the end of a tag, and that was it, so it was user clumsiness, took that thing out now my page was shifted, took the negative margin and all good. So try a validator and look for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-bottom: 0px;
```

This would do it
Btw ..nice site dude :)

Comment: `<body class="html front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-first page-node" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">` in the Dev Tools did not change the margin-bottom. I even tried it on both `html` and `body`, without results.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's some iframes/objects that are created by third party services that create this blank space. In my case, Google Adwords and Google Analytics was creating this. So, I removed by adding this CSS:

```
object[type="application/gas-events-cef"],
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"] {
    display: none !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    line-height: 0 !important;
    font-size: 0 !important;
    margin-top: -13px;
    float: left;
}
```

Maybe you will need to add some extra rules for your case. Hope that helps.